# Knowing number of elements in a relation from this information about equivalence classes.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am trying to understand this question: 
Let $A$ be a set with $24$ elements, and let $E$ be an equivalence relation on $A$. 
$E$  divides $A$ to $7$ equivalence classes in the following way: 
$3$ equivalence classes that has $4$ elements each. 
$4$ equivalence classes that has $3$ elements each. 
What is $|E|$ or how many elements are in the relation. 

My Attempt: 
I know that $[a]_E=\{b\in A \mid (a,b)\in E\}$ is the definition of equivalence class. so if I have $3$ equivalence classes with $4$ elements each that means I have $12$ pairs in $E$, but $E$ is a symmetric relation, so if $(a,b)\in E$ automatically we get $(b,a)\in E$ so $24$, and same thing for the other equivalence classes we get more $24$ pairs. but the answer was $84$. 
After thinking about it, I thought about the reflexive property and we can add $24$ pairs more since for each element in $A$ we get $(a,a)\in E$, but thinking about it again, in every equivalence class, I have already counted some of these elements, because every element is in it's own equivalence class, so I'm wondering why don't we subtract $7$ from the answer. 
All help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an equivalence class,  every element is paired with every element, every possible ordered pair is there.   So for instance, if one equivalence class is $\{a,b,c,d\}$ you have every possible ordered pair $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in\{a,b,c,d\}$,  i.e you have the full cross product and thus 16 ordered pairs relating those 4 elements.   Same thing with the 3 sets,  you have $3^2$ there for each one.  Add them up.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, thanks alot. I got a question of why is it like that, according to definition of equivalence relation $[a]_R$ it's all the elements that are in relation with $a$. is it from the property that if $b\in [a]_R$ then $[a]_R=[b]_R$? but aren't those the other equivalence classes given?

Comment: Transitivity, symmetry, and reflexivity combine to make it so that all the elements that share an equivalence class generate all the ordered pairs.   To be equivalent, you need to relate to each other.  Once you relate to each other, you need to relate with yourself( reflexivity) and relate the other way (symmetry).   If you add a third element to the class, transitivity then gets it relates to the other two,  and thus fills in the symmetric pairs as well

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The set $E$ contains all pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $x_1 \sim x_2$ or in other words it contains all pairs for which the two elements of the pair are in the same equivalence class. An equivalence class with three elements, say $x,y,z$ will make the following 9 pairs appear in $E$:
$$(x,x), (x,y), (x,z), (y,x), (y,y), (y,z), (z,x), (z,y), (z,z)$$
The pattern here is that each combination of two elements of the equvialence class is an element of $E$ resulting in $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ elements in E. Similarly, an equivalence class with 4 elements will result in 16 more elements in the set $E$ (since we have all possible pairs of two elements again). In general, one can conclude from that that an equivalence class with $n$ elements will make $n^2$ elements "join" the set $E$.

Adding everything up in this special case, we will get:
$$|E| = 4\cdot 9 + 3 \cdot 16 = 84$$

I hope this helps you.